# How to handle an apostrophe in an href in SAS

Tags: html, sas

I have a SAS program that sends out an email using HTML, but one of the folders I am trying to reference as a link contains an apostrophe:

```
%let body1 = %nrquote(
<ul>
<li><a href='\\server\Studies\Alzheimer's\Documents'>Alzheimer's Documents</a>
</ul>
) ;
```

This macro variable will be used in the following macro:

```
%macro sas_email(to=, subject=, body1=, body2=, body3=) ;
options 
  emailsys=smtp 
  emailhost=("smtp.gmail.com" port=465) ;

filename alert email to=(&to.) 
                     subject="&subject." 
                     content_type="text/html" 
                     debug ;

data _null_ ;
  file alert ;
  put "&body1." ;
  %if %length(&body2.) > 0 %then %do ;
  put "&body2." ;
  %end ;
  %if %length(&body3.) > 0 %then %do ;
  put "&body3." ;
  %end ;
run ;
%mend sas_email ;
```

As you can imagine, the apostrophe in `\Alzheimer's` causes issues.  Using double quotes instead of single gives me the error:

```
ERROR: A character operand was found in the %EVAL function or %IF condition where a numeric 
operand is required. The condition was: %length(&body1.) > 0
```

Comment: use encodeURIcomponent to create the href

Comment: oh sry in your case just use " instead of ' (thats not 2 quotes its one double quote)

Comment: alternatively you cna escape it with a '\'  : ...zheimer\'s\Doc...

Comment: I don't think URL's recognize backslash as meaning "escape".  They are used to separate directories.

Comment: @jonathan Heindl you mean `Alzheimer"s` ?

Comment: no (sry ) either  href='\\server\Studies\Alzheimer\'s\Documents'> or  href="\\server\Studies\Alzheimer's\Documents">

Comment: How are you going to use this macro variable?

Comment: @Tom I've updated my question to include the macro this variable will be used in

Comment: @jonathanHeindl The double quotes give me the error `ERROR: A character operand was found in the %EVAL function or %IF condition where a numeric
       operand is required.`

Comment: No need to not write BODY2 when it is empty. HTML files don't care about extra white space.

Answer (score 1):

HTML doesn't care if you use double quotes or single quotes.  So your generated HTML tag could look like this:

```
<a href="\\server\Studies\Alzheimer's\Documents">
```

If you want to add single quotes into a string enclosed in single quotes then encode it.

```
<a href='\\server\Studies\Alzheimer%27s\Documents'>
```

Since you are going to use the macro variable in a data step try just using `%BQUOTE()` to add macro quoting when creating the value. This should let you create a string that would look to SAS like unbalanced quotes.

```
%let body1 = %bquote(
<ul>
<li><a href="\\server\Studies\Alzheimer's\Documents">Alzheimer's Documents</a>
</ul>
) ;
%let body2=;
%let body3=;
```

Then when using it avoid trying to expand the macro variable by using `symget()` function to pull the value of the macro variable into an actual variable that you can then write using the `PUT` statement.

```
data _null_;
  file alert ;
  length str $32767;
  do i=1 to 3;
    str=symget(cats('body',i));
    put str ;
  end;
run;
```

Comment: The double quotes give me the error 
`ERROR: A character operand was found in the %EVAL function or %IF condition where a numeric operand is required.` and using `%27` points to a folder named `Alzheimer%27s` and not `Alzheimer's`.

Comment: Avoid trying to use the macro variable value to generate SAS code instead of HTML code.  So avoid `"&body"`.  If you really did need to generate a SAS string literal then try using `quote()` function. Like `%sysfunc(quote(%superq(body1),%str(%')))`